# TypeError No implicit conversion of (my class name)::ActiveRecord_Relation into Integer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

Whenever I try to access a model I have created named KlassAttribute. I am getting the following error and I don't fully understand why, or how to rectify this issue.

> > no implicit conversion of KlassAttribute::ActiveRecord_Relation into Integer

It happens for example when I load the rails console and type in KlassAttribute. I have 3 models and 3 tables. A klass has many klass_attributes and a klass_attribute has many klass_values.

The KlassAttribute constant is only being partially loaded due to the exception. I think my models and schema is correct, but what is causing my issue? If I omit 'validates' in my model, the model can be accessed just fine.

Schema.rb

```
create_table "klasses", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end

create_table "klass_attributes", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "klass_id"
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "destination"
    t.integer  "priority"
    t.integer  "value_type",  default: 0
    t.datetime "created_at",              null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",              null: false
end

add_index "klass_attributes", ["klass_id"], name: "index_klass_attributes_on_klass_id"

create_table "klass_values", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "key"
    t.string   "value"
    t.integer  "klass_attribute_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",         null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",         null: false
end

add_index "klass_values", ["klass_attribute_id"], name: "index_klass_values_on_klass_attribute_id"
```

klass.rb

```
class Klass < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :klass_attributes
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :klass_attributes, allow_destroy: true

    validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: true, length: { maximum: 255 }
end
```

klass_attribute.rb

```
class KlassAttribute < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :klass
    has_many :klass_values
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :klass_values, allow_destroy: true

    validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 }
end
```

klass_value.rb

```
class KlassValue < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :klass_attribute

    validates :key, length: { maximum: 255 }
    validates :value, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 }
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out why I had the error.
I had declared an enum in the KlassAttribute model that I didn't include in the source code above.

```
enum value_type: { array: 0, hash: 1}
```

The hash key in this enum was the cause of the error, so I renamed hash to something more appropriate and voila!